# visual studio and shared memory

Tags: visual-studio-2005

The project that i am right now handling is based on Interprocess Communication.

And am using Shared memory concept for this interprocess communication.

There are few files tat i need when i use shared memory concept for example sys/ipc.h, sys/shm.h

Are these files a part of visual studio insatallation or it is something that i hav to download.

I need to know if i need to reinstall visual studio 2005 and enable interprocess comunication so tat these files are automatically in hand for use.

check this link http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html

If this about link referes to Solaris which concept can i use to share memory in windows

**EDIT:** But CreateFileMapping is to map files right.I need to map a memory location to another process so as to use the data stored in that location..

Thank you i will try the code..

Answer (score 0):

The header files you mention are for UNIX-like systems. Downloading the headers would do you no good, as UNIX and Windows use different approaches to shared memory and IPC in general. See the [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28VS.85%29.aspx) and related functions for more info.

**Edit:** The link you quote refers explicitly to Solaris, not Windows. As I have already said, if you want to use shared memory on Windows you need to use the memory mapped file functions like CreateFileMapping. In outline, both processes need to create a file mapping and can then treat the mapped file as shared memory. There is an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/csharedstruct.aspx).

Comment: @neha: Completely wrong. The POSIX and Win32 APIs are different in just about every aspect, other than being "shared memory".

Comment: uh so which one do i use for sharing memory data between 2 processes which do not have their memory shared in window

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551(VS.85).aspx

Use CreateFileMapping and MapViewOfFile.